# Indexing a batched set of images

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

Suppose I have two index tensors and an image tensor, how can I sample the (x, y) points from the image?

```
img.shape # -> (batch x H x W x 3)
x.shape # -> (batch x H x W)
y.shape # -> batch x H x W)
```

(H x W being height x width)
Basically I want to perform something like a batch "shuffle" of the image pixel intensities.

Comment: @shai `height x width`

Comment: yes I know that, but if you only *sample* from H and W some y and x, why is the sample size HxW??

Comment: @shai So basically it's like a reshuffle of the coordinates. I'm sampling a mesh of coordinates (x, y) to re form a H x W image that consists of intensities from the original H x W image. That is the range of x and y are [0, height - 1], and [0, width - 1] respectively.

Comment: You want `output[a, b, c, d] == img[a, x[a, b, c], y[a, b, c], d]`, do I understand this correctly? (where `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are variables which iterate over batch, H, W and 3 respectively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want `output[a, b, c, d] == img[a, x[a, b, c], y[a, b, c], d]`, where a, b, c, d are variables which iterate over batch, H, W and 3, respectively. You can solve that by applying [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather) twice. As you can see in documentation it performs a similar indexing operation for a single dimension, so we would first gather on dim 1 with `x` as the `index` parameter and again on dim 2 with `y`. Unfortunately `gather` does not broadcast, so to deal with the trailing rgb dimension we have to add an extra dimension and manually repeat it. The code looks like this

```
import torch

# prepare data as in the example
batch, H, W = 2, 4, 5
img = torch.arange(batch * H * W * 3).reshape(batch, H, W, 3)
x = torch.randint(0, H, (batch, H, W))
y = torch.randint(0, W, (batch, H, W))

# deal with `torch.gather` not broadcasting
x = x.unsqueeze(3).repeat(1, 1, 1, 3)
y = y.unsqueeze(3).repeat(1, 1, 1, 3)

# do the actual indexing
x_shuff = torch.gather(img, dim=1, index=x)
output = torch.gather(x_shuff, dim=2, index=y)
```

Comment: Is there any way to repeat without having the memory overhead? I'm running into GPU memory issues